# Ruby on Rails: How can I edit database.yml for postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Rails new app.

The current database.yml is like that:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I need to edit this for postgresql database.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Simply:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Source: [Configuring Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 14):

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: name
  username: hading
  password: my_db_password
  pool: 5 # not mandatory
  timeout: 5000 # not mandatory
  host: localhost
  port: your postgresql port number (5432 or 5433)
```

Answer (score 6):

As Zabba said it's

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password:
```

As mentioned in the [Configuring Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database). But you might want an additional `min_messages: WARNING`, to get rid of [the nasty NOTICE messages postgresql gives you during a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296290/notices-for-sequence-after-running-migration-in-rails-on-postgresql-application). So my `database.yml` entry looks like this

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password:
  min_messages: WARNING
```

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in generating new app with postgres default:

```
rails new myapp --database=postgresql
```

as mentioned here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Answer (score 3):

```
 development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: name
  username: hading
  password: my_db_password
  host: localhost # not mandatory
  pool: 5 # not mandatory
  timeout: 5000 # not mandatory
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
rails new app_name --database=postgresql
```

or if existing application try

```
 development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_dev
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to have the common values in &default and then have individual values for the other environments, which can be based on environment variables:

```
default: &default
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  port:     <%= ENV.fetch("POSTGRESQL_PORT", "5432") %>
  pool:     <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD", "myS3cr3tP4ssw0rd") %>
  host:     <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_HOST'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_DB'] %>-development
  host: db

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_DB'] %>-test
  host: db

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_DB'] %>
```

Here all the values can come from environment variables (if you use Docker or Bitbucket Pipelines) or you can have them in your .env files.

Answer (score 0):

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: utf8
 database: best_solution
 username: username
 password: password
 host: localhost
 pool: 2
 timeout: 5000
```