# Deploying Cloud9 to Heroku - Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, cloud9-ide

Gotten to databases portion of deploying C9 to heroku but I keep running int othis error. Postgresql is already installed on cloud9 but I'm having trouble. I get this error when I run "postgresql" into terminal

> ryanreese09@codefund:~/workspace/ruby-getting-started (master) $ psql
>   ry Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix
>   domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#declare-app-dependencies

I haven't run bundle install since the postgresql command didn't work. It's not running. Would anyone be willing to getthrown on my workspace as a member and help? I've been messing with this all weekend. All the various threads I've search on here don't quite help. The don't help with getting the sockets set up. Please don't flame. I'm new.

EDIT- [Ruby on Rails: How can i edit database.yml for postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689097/ruby-on-rails-how-can-i-edit-database-yml-for-postgresql)

Changed my database.yml file but literally nothing changed. So I reverted it back to the default database.yml file for now (that came with installation)

Comment: Why would I wonder about that? All I care about is my code issue.

Comment: Did you run 'sudo service postgresql start'? After it's started you should be able to connect using 'psql'

Answer (score 2):

> $ sudo service postgresql start