# How do I avoid the implicit sequence on the id field during rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, primary-key, sequence

I am attempting to create a table in rails.. I need to be able to set the id's to data that's coming in because I have three (or more) sources, and their ID's must match.

I'm setting the ID's manually, based on data I get in.

When I create the table with a migration, I get the message
"will create implicit sequence"
I don't want this to happen... How do I avoid it?

I know why it's always there.. but sometimes we need customization no? :)

Comment: Please, read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296290/notices-for-sequence-after-running-migration-in-rails-on-postgresql-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActiveRecord make the :primary_key column auto_increment by default. Maybe you have to create the primary key by yourself if you don't want it auto_increment.

```
create_table :table_name, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :id
  t.timestamps
end
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)")
```