# Rails (PostgreSQL?) implicit sequence/index warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, database-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NOTICES for sequence after running migration in rails on postgresql Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296290/notices-for-sequence-after-running-migration-in-rails-on-postgresql-application)

Using PostgreSQL for development & test databases (as well as production). When I `rake db:test:prepare` my **PostgreSQL** `theapp_test` database I get these messages for each table:

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "events_id_seq" for serial column "events.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "events_pkey" for table "events"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"
...
```

I do not get these notices with `rake db:migrate` on `theapp_development`. And I haven't noticed them in production. What does it mean and should I work to get rid of them?

FYI - This didn't occur in the past when I have used MySQL (or SQLite3 for that matter) for testing...

Comment: -1 because it's a duplicate of a question trivially found in the same tags by searching for the error message.

Comment: I searched 3 different ways before posting. must have missed it. sry. happens.

Comment: @Meltemi np, sorry. Worth mentioning what you've tried/looked at in posts. -0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That's just Postgres being awesome and automatically creating stuff for you that you actually want. It's not a warning it's just an FYI

Comment: It really is a drag to not have a PK automatically indexed .. I'd say "doing what it should" (or "doing what I expect SQL Server to do" ;-) vs "awesome" .. pgsql is just more verbose about the matter.

Comment: +1 for pointing out is a *NOTICE* (aka "info") and not a warning ..

Answer (score 11):

You can silence these messages by adding (or uncommenting) a line in `config/database.yml`:

```
# config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  min_messages: WARNING  # this line silences those NOTICE messages
```